# Как распарсить имя файла?

Tags: java

Есть задача: приходит файл, в его имени содержится информация, её надо выдернуть и раскидать по таблице в БД. Посоветуйте, какими методами для этого можно воспользоваться?

Пример названия файла:

> dokument_Статья 100938_06072014 нач = 10,00, кон = 11,00 342554658.txt

Comment: file.getName() и дальше парсить полученную строку

Comment: Зависит от ваших потребностей. Если в имени файла пробелы, попробуйте `Split`. Иначе воспользуйтесь регулярками. Без примера мы не можем знать, что вам надо.

Comment: @Denis пример добавил к описанию вопроса

Comment: Вы близки! А теперь мы не знаем, какие данные вам надо получить.

Comment: Берете пакет `java.util.regex` пишите паттерн регулярки и находите совпадение через `Matcher`..........https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html ......как пример `String ISBN = "ISBN: 123-456-789-112-3, ISBN: 1234567891123";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d-?){13}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ISBN);

while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group());` ............ остается вам создать свою регулярку под те данные, которые вы хотите вытащить и вперед

Comment: Методы это либо парсить регулярными выражениями, либо по символам разделения. Зависит от имени файла, всегда ли подчиняется какому то шаблону?

Comment: regexp чем не подходит?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский лады я так и сделал, подскажите ещё я создал паттерн  `String pattern = "\\s+|,\\s*";` и поместил его в ` String inputString = fileName; 
                     
                    String[] splitResult = inputString.split(pattern);` как теперь из массива достать результаты и сохранить их в нужные переменные ?

Comment: @VargSieg ....эм...... берете переменную с каким-либо именем и кладете туда.....не понимаю суть проблемы.... строку к строке.....для числа делаете `Integer.parseInt` для doube другой парс......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтоб распарсить строки, имеющие одинаковый формат, достаточно воспользоваться пакетом `java.util.regex`, составить правильное регулярное выражение, вытащив необходимы данные. За паттерн и совпадения отвечают [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) и [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) соответственно.

Как пример:

```
String ISBN = "ISBN: 123-456-789-112-3, ISBN: 1234567891123"; 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d-?){13}"); 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ISBN); 

while (matcher.find()) 
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

вытащит

```
123-456-789-112-3
1234567891123
```

Все результаты получатся в виде строк. Поэтому после составления правильно регулярки, если нужно преобразовать к типу, то используем соответствующие методы у данных классов. Например:

```
String testString = "666"; 
int testInteger = Integer.parseInt(testString);
```

или

```
String testString = "666.666"; 
double testDouble = Double.parseDouble(testString);
```

Если дробное число имеет запятую `666,666`, а нужен разделитель точка, то можно использовать [java.text.NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
Number number = format.parse("1,234");
double d = number.doubleValue();
```